# How to keep values in sync between an XML configuration file and a database table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I'm structuring in a hierarchical way in levels. By example.

```
Category 7
    Objective 7.1  [GeneralExpectation='']
        A  [Expectation='']
        B  [Expectation='']
        C  [Expectation='']
    Objective 7.2  [GeneralExpectation='']
        A  [Expectation='']
        B  [Expectation='']
    Objective 7.3  [GeneralExpectation='']
        A  [Expectation='']
Category 8
    ...
```

I guess it will be convenient to store this information in a xml file instead in a database.

```
<Levels>
  <Level Id=7>
    <Categories>
      <Category Id=1 Name="Numbers, Operations, and Quantitative Reasoning" Expectation="The student will demonstrate an understanding of numbers, operations, and quantitative reasoning.">
        <Objective Id="7.1" Name="Number, operation, and quantitative reasoning." GeneralExpectation="The student represents and uses numbers in a variety of equivalent forms. The student is expected to">
          <SubObjective Id="A" Expectation="compare and order integers and positive rational numbers; Supporting Standard" />
          <SubObjective Id="B" Expectation="convert between fractions, decimals, whole numbers, and percents mentally, on paper, [or with a calculator]; and Readiness Standard" />
        </Objective>
      </Category>
      <Category Id=2 Name="Patterns, Relationships, and Algebraic Reasoning" Expectation="The student will demonstrate an understanding of patterns, relationships, and algebraic reasoning.">
      </Category>
    </Categories>
  </Level>
</Levels>
```

I did this because I need to access this information in a `TreeView` control in WPF. But at the same time, I have a table in my SQL Database where needs to store the Level objective which the user is utilizing:  `7.1A, 7.1B, 7.1C, 7.2A`.

Is this a good practice? Or I'm not preserving the relationship between the two data.

Answer (score 0):

@DarfZon, I would keep the data in one format (my suggestion would be SQL Server if your other data is also relational). You can retrieve the the relational data in SQL Server in a hierarchical format using the SQL Server's powerful XML syntax and the [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107) clause.